# How to refresh Chrome remotely?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, browser, signal, refresh

I have Chrome running in kiosk mode (it displays my HTML/CSS/JS application - so I have control over the whole stack).

From time to time, I need to refresh its static content, that is reload the HTML, JS and CSS files. This is equivalent to pressing <kbd>Shift-F5</kbd>.

The problem is that this is an installation without a keyboard/mouse so I currently reboot the machine (a Raspberry Pi) to "refresh" the display and would like to use a less intrusive method.

**Is there a way to send Chrome a signal from the command line so that it refreshes the page?**

Notes:

- Ultimately I can use a `Refresh` header but would like to avoid as much as possible (I prefer in that case to reboot the machine)
- The RPi starts `xinit` in `rc.local`, which in turns (after some other commands) starts Chrome (and hangs) so I cannot just restart the browser.

Comment: Why avoid the refresh header?  That is the obvious solution.  If you want to be fancy, take a look at how drudgereport does it - after every refresh you end up back in the same <div> where you were before the refresh.

Comment: Can you kill chrome remotely and restart it? What about changing your code so it refreshes itself after 15 minutes past a counter?